# Updating axis type in Bokeh

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I am currently using Bokeh to build an interactive data visualization tool in a Jupyter notebook. My goal is that the user can change what data is plotted in a scatter plot, meaning that the plot update should handle both categorical and numerical data. This is where I run into trouble.

When I change the data type to be plotted, the points in the scatter plot update fine, but the axis ticks and range does not (so the view is not updating correctly). I have tried specifying the x_range and y_range, but that does not seem to do the trick.

A minimal example of my update function:

```
def update(attr, old, new):
    # this seems to work fine.
    new_data = ColumnDataSource(dict=(x=x, y=y, c=c))
    src.data.update(new_data.data)

    # change type of y and x axes
    # e.g. x_range goes from Range1d to FactorRange
    p.x_range = FactorRange()
    p.x_range.factors = sorted(set(source.data['x']))

    # or y_range goes from FactorRange to Range1d
    p.y_range = Range1d()
    p.y_range.start = min(source.data['y'])
    p.y_range.end = max(source.data['y'])

    ...
    push_notebook(handle=p)
```

Can anyone help? I have been googling quite a lot, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Edit: The change of x and y comes from two widgets, btw.

Edit 2: reproducible example https://gist.github.com/hmmartiny/d8b0596b4028de66bdc72e8848f10a7e

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out by looking at the plotting code [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/9611f34f44f50c110202ec841b1cf07e249f3464/bokeh/plotting/figure.py#L159) and [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/9611f34f44f50c110202ec841b1cf07e249f3464/bokeh/plotting/helpers.py#L451).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import LogScale

p = figure()  # makes a plot with y_axis_type linear
p.circle(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 20, 200])
p.y_scale = LogScale()
```